# Passing nested double quotes within child process

Tags: bash, rust

I am trying to pass this string as an argument for a bash command with `Command::new("/bin/bash")` in Rust.

```bash
version=$(awk -F ' = ' '$$1 ~ /version/ { gsub(/[\"]/, "", $$2); printf("%s",$$2) }' Cargo.toml)
```

The args handle accepts string as an argument so I have to pass the command in the following manner

```rust
Command::new("/bin/bash").arg("-c").arg("package=$(awk -F ' = ' '$$1 ~ /version/ { gsub(/[\"]/, "", $$2); printf("%s",$$2) }' Cargo.toml)")
```

The problem is having nested double quotes in the command argument which does not allow the program to compile. Specially inside the printf statement and the null string (`""`) inside gsub.
This command extracts a version from the Cargo.toml package. I know we can extract versions from the env variable but due to constraints I am not allowed to change the command. I would like to know a way to escape double quotes inside string statements within bash like these.

Comment: just out of curiousity, does Rust allow using octal codes (or hex codes, less ideal though) in those quoted commands to circumvent this double quoting issue ? e.g. using \042\042 instead lieu of ( " " ) , or \044 in lieu of  ( " $ " ) etc etc,

Comment: yes Rust allows octal codes.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [raw string literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals) when you have to add a lot of double quotes in strings. This works:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("/bin/bash")
        .args(["-c", r#"awk -F ' = ' '$$1 ~ /version/ { gsub(/[\"]/, "", $$2); printf("%s",$$2) }' Cargo.toml"#])
        .output()
        .unwrap();
    dbg!(output);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e7e1d1db217279101b8ef4e31a653e50)

In your original code you were assigning the value to `version` but not printing or using it. I also modified it to output the value to stdout.

You can also call `awk` directly:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("awk")
        .args(["-F", " = ", r#"$$1 ~ /version/ { gsub(/[\"]/, "", $$2); printf("%s",$$2) }"#, "Cargo.toml"])
        .output()
        .unwrap();
    dbg!(output);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6707e4d289ee2cd0df437d2319b4b63)